# No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found - ASP.NET core 2.1

Tags: c#, authorization, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm working with ASP.NET Core 2.1 WebApi project, in that we've used token based authentication

```
public class UserIdentityFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{    
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        StringValues authorizationHeaders;
        if (!context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out authorizationHeaders))
            return;
        ...
        ...
    }   
}
```

And having middleware for error handling:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, ILogger logger, IAppConfiguration appConfiguration)
{            
    try
    {
        await _next(context);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {               
        await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex, logger, appConfiguration);
    }
}
```

It's working fine if I pass header for authorize method, however missing header for the same gives an error `No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.`

Here I have two questions:

1) It is okay to send 500 with this exception to user end, when header not specified?

2) How to handle this scenario and passing meaningful message "header is missing " or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It is okay to send 500 with this exception to user end, when header not specified?

I'm afraid that's not a good idea.

The `500` status code indicates there's a server error. When clients send a request without a token , it make no sense to tell the client that "an internal error happens". A better way is to send `401` to challenge the user or send `403` to forbid .

> How to handle this scenario and passing meaningful message "header is missing" or something?

Firstly, I have to say that I don't think using a `AuthorizationFilter` to authenticate user is a good option.

As the error describes , **the error is thrown because there was no `AuthenticationScheme` was specified, and there was no `DefaultChallengeScheme` found**.

To fix the bug , **simply specify a authentication scheme**. For example , if you're using `JwtToken` , you should add a `AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)` or use a `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes ="JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme")]` attribute

Otherwise, if you would like to custom the way it authenticates user (for example , custom a token-based authentication), you should create a new Token Authentication Handler. There's already a built-in abstract `AuthenticationHandler` class :

```
public abstract class AuthenticationHandler<TOptions> : IAuthenticationHandler 
    where TOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions, new()
{
     // ...
}
```

**Since the default `HandleChallengeAsync()` will send a `401` response, you could simply extend the`AuthenticationHandler` and override the `HandleChallengeAsync()` method to custom your own message to challenge user** :

```
public class OurOwnAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<ApiKeyAuthOpts>
{
    public OurOwnAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<ApiKeyAuthOpts> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) 
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }


    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        StringValues authorizationHeaders;
        if (!context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out authorizationHeaders))
             return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
        // ... return AuthenticateResult.Fail(exceptionMessage);
        // ... return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket)
    } 

    protected override Task HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 401;
        var message = "tell me your token";
        Response.Body.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    protected override Task HandleForbiddenAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 403;
        var message = "you have no rights";
        Response.Body.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

}
```

Lastly , you need also register the authentication handler :

```
services.AddAuthentication("OurOwnAuthN")
        .AddScheme<OurOwnAuthNOpts,OurOwnAuthNHandler>("OurOwnAuthN","Our Own AuthN Scheme",opts=>{
            // ...
        });
```

If you don't want set the "OurOwnAuthN" as the default authentication scheme , you can use a `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes ="OurOwnAuthN")]` to protect your resources :

```
// your `ConfigureServices()`
services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddScheme<OurOwnAuthNOpts,OurOwnAuthNHandler>("OurOwnAuthN","Our Own AuthN Scheme",opts=>{
            // ...
        });


// your action method :
// GET api/values/5
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes ="OurOwnAuthN")]        
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
{
    return "value";
}
```

if a user send a request without a token or with a incorrect token , the response from server will be :

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Kestrel
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpccmVwb3J0XDIwMThcMTBcMThcU08uYXV0aGVudGljYXRpb25TY2hlbWUsIE5vIERlZmF1bHRDaGFsbGVuZ2VTY2hlbWVcQXBwXEFwcFxhcGlcdmFsdWVzXDE=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

tell me your token
```

**[Edit]**

If you're using Jwt Token , your can use the following code to register JwtBearer Authentication :

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
    };
});
```

**[Edit2]**

The JwtBearer AuthenticationHandler **provides a `Challenge` to custom the `WWW-Authenticate`** :

```
    .AddJwtBearer(options => {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
        };
        options.Challenge ="tell me your token";;
    })
```

and the response will be :

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Kestrel
WWW-Authenticate: tell me your token, error="invalid_token"
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpccmVwb3J0XDIwMThcMTBcMThcU08uYXV0aGVudGljYXRpb25TY2hlbWUsIE5vIERlZmF1bHRDaGFsbGVuZ2VTY2hlbWVcQXBwXEFwcFxhcGlcdmFsdWVzXDE=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 0
```

Note the `WwW-Authenticate` header .

Another way is to **forward the challenge** by :

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options => {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
        };
        options.ForwardChallenge = "OurOwnAuthN";
    })
    .AddScheme<OurOwnAuthNOpts,OurOwnAuthNHandler>("OurOwnAuthN","Our Own Authentication Scheme",opts=>{
            // ...
     });
```

and the response will be :

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Kestrel
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpccmVwb3J0XDIwMThcMTBcMThcU08uYXV0aGVudGljYXRpb25TY2hlbWUsIE5vIERlZmF1bHRDaGFsbGVuZ2VTY2hlbWVcQXBwXEFwcFxhcGlcdmFsdWVzXDE=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

tell me your token
```

Comment: Registered `services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);` and added `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` However, getting error of `"No authentication handlers are registered. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().Add[SomeAuthHandler](\"Bearer\",...)?`

Comment: @Div I can't post too much words in comments :( , so I update my answer for how to register JwtBearer Authentication Hander

Comment: Yes, this is fine, and the way of custom message remains the same for jwt tokens?

Comment: @Div I've updated my answer to show how to custom the challenge of JwtBearer authentication handler.

Comment: Hi, could you please help me? I need to add refresh token in my project(JWT), however I don't want to store refresh token in DB, is there any approach for the same?

Comment: @Div You don't need to store token. Jwt Token is stored on clients and validated on server.   Simply create a new token and send them to client will be ok.

Comment: Thanks  for the reply! What should be the expire time of refresh token then?

Comment: @Div That depends on your scenario .There're a lot of websites having their  token expired in two hours .

Comment: @Div It's the client's responsibility to store token ,send requests with token, and ask for a new token.  The Server should not care about too much things. They just generate token and validate token.

Comment: Okay, so what I understood is, we'll have two type of tokens 1)Access  Token 2) Refresh token. also we'd need to define access token expiry time and refresh token expiry time, **(access token expiry < refresh token expiry)**  once access token expired they will call refresh token method, server will validate it and issue a new access token. But the question is what should need to be done when refresh token get expired?

Comment: @Div I don't know whether there's a standard way to do that . But I used to  issue a accessToken(expired in 2 hours) & a refreshToken(expired in 2.1 hours)  at the same time . The client ask for new tokens using the refreshToken ,  replace old accessToken and refreshToken with new ones .

Comment: @Div Even if the refresh token expired at some time , the client will also be able to login again and got a new accessToken and refresh token. The server doesn't care about that . They just validate the token .

Comment: @Div Sorry, I misunderstood your question about refresh token . I thought you're trying to save accessToken .  People usually save refresh token somewhere. If you don't want save a refresh token , simply issue a new JwtToken named as refresh token , which is treated as a refresh token and can be used as refresh token only.